# Validate AntiForgeryToken in WebAPI controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've been following the technique outlined here:
http://blog.novanet.no/anti-forgery-tokens-using-mvc-web-api-and-angularjs/

The scenario:
I have an MVC4 application making AngularJS ajax calls a separate MVC4 WebApi application.  These applications are completely separate and may eventually live on separate web servers.

What I'm seeing is that as the process goes, I can generate a token on the client (View), and then I can add a custom header attribute to be sent along with the ajax request.  When the request hits the WebApi, I can see and parse out the token, but when I try to validate it, I get this message:

The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "me", but the current user is "".

I'm thinking when I generate the token on the View, I'm building a token that relies on the currently authenticated user, and that's what get sent to the WebApi.  So my question is this:

What is the standard way to lock down a WebApi when the WebApi is designed to be flexible to accept requests from a public website (anonymous access)?  Do I need to build my own token mechanism that gets validated in the WebApi?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right - you only need anti-forgery tokens if the web API authenticates using credentials that the browser implicitly flows with the request (e.g., cookies). Then you need anti-forgery tokens to protect against CSRF. In your scenario, the anti-forgery tokens won't work and aren't even needed, because the Web API isn't authenticating via the cookie credentials. The better way to authorize web API requests is using access tokens (OAuth2)

Comment: That makes sense in an environment that requires authentication.  In my scenario, I have a public site (non-authenticated) making ajax requests to the WebApi site.  I don't want a WebAPI that is accessible by anyone.  Do I restrict requests by what IP address the request is coming from?  What other options are there?  I was thinking sending a token and validating it on the WebApi would've solved that.

Comment: Ah, got it. Then I think you'd want to issue a token - it's basically an OAuth flow without requiring user login. e.g., have the MVC app issue a JWT token that the Web API accepts. **BIG CAVEAT**: I'm really not a security guru. You might want to ask that specific question on security.stackexchange.